# Can I use EC2-type secuirty groups with Amazon Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

One thin I love about using EC2 is how I can choose which IPs are allowed to talk to each other over what ports.  But when I look at Amazon DynamoDb, I do not see anything like this.  Just user-type access, which is a different kind of security altogether.

Does anyone know if we can restrict DynamoDB access by IP, using EC2 security groups?  If not, is there another Amazon data store that does work this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have noted, DynamoDB doesn't use security groups, it uses IAM users/roles for access. There is no way to add security groups to DynamoDB. By default nothing has access to your DynamoDB tables. To grant access from certain EC2 instances or Lambda functions you would modify the IAM role assigned to those servers/functions to grant them access.

> If not, is there another Amazon data store that does work this way?

If that is literally your only requirement for a data store, then look into RDS or run something yourself on an EC2 server.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I will go with an RDS instance for this.

Answer (score 2):

Both the question & accepted answer happened too long ago. I'm stumbling upon the same requirement today (2021) and I can confirm that we are now able to restrict access into our DynamoDB by "source IP addresses". Decided to jot down my finding in case it ever helps someone out there :)

Note that the process itself is undocumented, but it actually works for me:

1. Create a new IAM policy. Here I attach a sample one that I use:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account-id>:table/<table-name>",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xx.yy.zz.ww",
                        "some.ip.addre.ss"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create an IAM user, assign the above policy to that user (or its group). Make sure this user can programmatically access AWS resources (e.g. with AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key)
3. Connect to your DynamoDB from your application code as you would normally do it. You will notice now that: if your application code is run from a machine whose IP address is outside the whitelisted `aws:SourceIp` provided in your policy (above), the DynamoDB operation will fail (although there is no specific reason given in the error response):
   [image]

Then again, as of June 2021, this approach is either undocumented, or it is documented somewhere but I just failed to find it. If you try it and it doesn't work for you, please feel free to drop a comment and (if I'm still alive by the time) I'll try my best to help investigate!